# Cannot get confirm box to appear onsubmit

Tags: php, javascript, confirm, onsubmit

I am trying to use `onsubmit="return confirm('Do you really want to submit the form?')"` to make a warning appear before a user deletes items by clicking the submit button. I cannot get a confirm box to appear it just continues directly to deleting the item.

Can anyone see in my code where I could be going wrong? I have tried changing double and single quotes but no effort has got the confirm box to appear.

My code is as follows.

```
    echo '<td> <form method="post" action="deleteassign.php" name="deleteassignform"
 id="deleteassignform" onsubmit="return confirm('Do you really want to submit the form?')">';
    echo '<input type="hidden" name="quizidvalue" id="quizidvalue" value="'.$sendquizid.'" />';
    echo '<input type="hidden" name="classidvalue" id="classidvalue" value="'.$sendclassid.'" />';
    echo '<input type="submit" name="deleteassignment" id="deleteassignment" value="Delete This Assignment"> </form> </td> </tr>';
```

Comment: You probably should use [htmlspecialchars](http://php.net/htmlspecialchars) when echoing `$sendquizid`.

Comment: Now your quoting goes nuts, you're actually closing your `echo` statement. You should use the form `?><td> <form …<?= htmlspecialchars($sendquizid)?>…<?php`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change your:

```
return confirm('Do you really want to submit the form?')
```

to

```
return confirm(\'Do you really want to submit the form?\')
```

That should sort out any qouting issues this gives you, as it is definitely qouted incorrectly.

Answer (score 1):

In order to output...

```
onsubmit="return confirm('Do you really want to submit the form?')"
```

...you need to escape your quotes properly on the PHP side. Try the following (note the backslashes before the single quotes):

```
echo '<td> <form method="post" action="deleteassign.php" name="deleteassignform"
 id="deleteassignform" onsubmit="return confirm(\'Do you really want to submit the form?\')">';
```

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you put the code in the button directly?

```
<input type="submit" name="deleteassignment" id="deleteassignment" 
value="Delete This Assignment" onclick="return confirm('Do you really want to delete?')">
```

Comment: The quoting is still wrong. And now it only works when clicking that button, not when pressing Enter in an input field.

Comment: that's bad user experience. Why would a user want to delete when pressing enter??. Also, your form doesn't have any input field for users to focus!!!!!!

Answer (score 0):

Your quoting is wrong. You can better use this form, so all quotes are correct:

```
?><td> <form method="post" action="deleteassign.php" name="deleteassignform"
id="deleteassignform" onsubmit="return confirm('Do you really want to submit the form?')">
<input type="hidden" name="quizidvalue" id="quizidvalue" value="<?= htmlspecialchars($sendquizid) ?>" />
<input type="hidden" name="classidvalue" id="classidvalue" value="<?= htmlspecialchars($sendclassid) ?>" />
<input type="submit" name="deleteassignment" id="deleteassignment" value="Delete This Assignment"> </form> </td> </tr>
<?php
```

Answer (score 0):

The code outputted by your code should look like this:

```
<form method="post" action="deleteassign.php" name="deleteassignform"
 id="deleteassignform" onSubmit="return confirm('Do you really want to submit the form?');">
```

Note the quoting inside the `confirm` function.